# How to add cross-compiler to the PATH

Tags: path, makefile, environment-variables, cross-compiling

I recently downloaded and installed ARM cross-compiler *CodeSourcery* on my host machine running Ubuntu 13.04.

I want to cross-compile a kernel driver by running `make`. Makefile contains parameter `CROSS_COMPILE := arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`. How can I add cross-compiler to the PATH?

Is it the same by editing Makefile with the path that cross-compiler is located?

e.g. `CROSS_COMPILE := /home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`

Answer (score 2):

You need to export following things:

```
export ARCH=arm
export PATH=/home/demetres/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/:$PATH
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
```

After doing this you can call `make menuconfig`, `make` etc.

You can put all these export commands into a script file and invoke via `source` command before compiling/configuring your kernel.

Comment: I've noticed that despite adding this to the path via the aforementioned exports, for some packages like buidroot, I still need to explicitly specify it on the CLI

Answer (score 0):

You should not edit `Makefile` for this, most of the times, temporary changing of `PATH` is enough.

```
orgPATH=$PATH
export PATH=/home/demetres/CodeSourcery:$PATH
make
export PATH=$orgPATH
```